# Pandas. How to reset index in a df that is resampled

Tags: pandas

Possible newbie question.
I have a df of daily stock prices;

```
print(df.head())
```

it prints the following:

```
                 High         Low        Open       Close    Volume   Adj Close       100ma       250ma
Date                                                                                                    
2015-01-02  314.750000  306.959991  312.579987  308.519989   2783200  308.519989  308.519989  308.519989
2015-01-05  308.380005  300.850006  307.010010  302.190002   2774200  302.190002  305.354996  305.354996
2015-01-06  303.000000  292.380005  302.239990  295.290009   3519000  295.290009  302.000000  302.000000
2015-01-07  301.279999  295.329987  297.500000  298.420013   2640300  298.420013  301.105003  301.105003
2015-01-08  303.140015  296.109985  300.320007  300.459991   3088400  300.459991  300.976001  300.976001
```

next I wanted to resample it and change it into a weekly chart:

```
df_ohcl = df.resample('W',loffset=pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6)).apply({
'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min','Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum'})
```

it gives me the right weekly values:

```
                  Open        High        Low       Close   Volume
Date                    
2014-12-29  312.579987  314.750000  306.959991  308.519989  2783200
2015-01-05  307.010010  308.380005  292.380005  296.929993  14614300
2015-01-12  297.559998  301.500000  285.250000  290.739990  20993900
2015-01-19  292.589996  316.929993  286.390015  312.390015  22999200
2015-01-26  311.820007  359.500000  299.329987  354.529999  41666500
```

I want to now move this information to matplotlib,
as well as convert the dates to the mdates version. Since I'm just going to graph the columns in Matplotlib, I actually don't want the date to be an index anymore, so I tried:

```
df_ohlc.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

### get an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-149-6c0c324e68a8> in <module>
      5 '''
      6 
----> 7 df_ohlc.reset_index(inplace=True)
      8 
      9 df_ohcl.head()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reset_index(self, level, drop, inplace, col_level, col_fill)
   4602                 # to ndarray and maybe infer different dtype
   4603                 level_values = _maybe_casted_values(lev, lab)
-> 4604                 new_obj.insert(0, name, level_values)
   4605 
   4606         new_obj.index = new_index

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   3494         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   3495         value = self._sanitize_column(column, value, broadcast=False)
-> 3496         self._data.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
   3497 
   3498     def assign(self, **kwargs) -> "DataFrame":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   1171         if not allow_duplicates and item in self.items:
   1172             # Should this be a different kind of error??
-> 1173             raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {item}, already exists")
   1174 
   1175         if not isinstance(loc, int):

ValueError: cannot insert ('level_0', ''), already exists
```

How can I fix it, so Date becomes just another column?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `inplace=False` will resolve.   You've changed number of rows so you cannot map back to previous cardinality

Comment: Thanks Rob, but changing to inplace=False didn't do it, Same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be convenient to keep the date column as an index, for plotting in MatPlotLib.  Here is an example:

First, import packages and re-create the weekly data frame:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = '''Date Open High Low Close Volume
2014-12-29  312.579987  314.750000  306.959991  308.519989  2783200
2015-01-05  307.010010  308.380005  292.380005  296.929993  14614300
2015-01-12  297.559998  301.500000  285.250000  290.739990  20993900
2015-01-19  292.589996  316.929993  286.390015  312.390015  22999200
2015-01-26  311.820007  359.500000  299.329987  354.529999  41666500
'''

weekly = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=' +', engine='python')
            .assign(Date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Date'], 
                                                    format='%Y-%m-%d', 
                                                    errors='coerce'))
            .set_index('Date'))

                  Open        High         Low       Close    Volume
Date                                                                
2014-12-29  312.579987  314.750000  306.959991  308.519989   2783200
2015-01-05  307.010010  308.380005  292.380005  296.929993  14614300
2015-01-12  297.559998  301.500000  285.250000  290.739990  20993900
2015-01-19  292.589996  316.929993  286.390015  312.390015  22999200
2015-01-26  311.820007  359.500000  299.329987  354.529999  41666500
```

Next, create the plot.  The index (dates, in weekly steps) become the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

for field in ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']:
    ax.plot(weekly[field], label=field)
    
ax.legend()
plt.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create column that will retain date info

```
df['Date'] = df.index
```

Set generated range that is length of DataFrame as index

```
df.index = range(len(df))
```